# Simple question about multivariate/multiclass classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, naive-bayes

From this link [Text Classiﬁcation using Naive Bayes](http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/inf2b/learnnotes/inf2b-learn-note07-2up.pdf), there are two models described for classification, Naive and Bernoulli. My question is if i want to make this classifiers for multiclass (multivariate) classification i should use techniques like: one vs. one/rest and etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of one-by-one comparison, why not characterizing the entire probability distribution. Let $p(c_i | n, \vec{\theta}_i)$ be the posterior probability that the new observation $n$ belongs to a class $c_i$, then according to the Bayes' theorem:

\begin{equation}
p(c_i | n, \vec{\theta}_i ) = 
p(c_i) \frac{p(n | c_i, \vec{\theta}_i)}
{\sum_{k=1}^{M}  p(n | c_k, \vec{\theta}_k)p(c_k)}  ,
\end{equation}

where $M$ is number of classes which can be in general bigger than two. Having the above probability distribution, you can decide on class assignment for an item $n$ according to the maximum posterior probability. Note that the likelihood function $p(n | c_i, \vec{\theta}_i)$ can be set according to what modeling technique you're going to use. For example, for a Naive Bayes classifier, the features $\vec{\theta}_i$ are assumed to be independent.

Comment: I just have one more question, is this good for text classification?

Comment: yeah sure, it's good for everything. In fact, it's not the matter of bein good or bad, it's just right way for doing this.

Comment: Thanks, i asked because i have some hard time with computing the estimate :D